# Why Chinese "h" often corresponds to Sino-Japanese "k"?

Tags: words, kanji, pronunciation, furigana, proper-nouns

Shanghai is Shanhai in Japanese / しゃんはい

However, 深海 is shinkai (shēnhǎi in Chinese).

Why does it seem like the Japanese switched the letter "h" to "k"? I know the kana, and "h" would go to a "b" sound, "k" would go to a "g" sound. I am just not understanding why they would say "shinkai" (if not "shenkai") and not "shinhai" in the above example.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151311/discussion-on-question-by-watashinopiza-why-in-japanese-do-they-use-kai-instea); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @chocolate Was that for me or another user? I am unclear why comments had to be moved. It doesn't show what comments were moved.

Comment: When the comment section gets long we often move it.  It has nothing to do with you personally.

Comment: I voted to close. I think you need to clarify what you are after. Is it how the Japanese reading for 海=kai developed historically or why the modern Japanese reads 上海 as shanhai and 深海 as shinkai? In case of the former, the existing answer should answer the question; in case of the latter, it just because 上海 is a place name and the modern Chinese pronunciation sounds that way to Japanese ears (mostly). There's not much 'why' here. If you think I misinterpret your question, you would better provide more examples to clarify the question.

Comment: @sundowner - This poster is confused beyond help as you can see from how the chat went. (I was tempted to say the word 電話 was also ... but refrained from it...) The post, meanwhile, has gotten its maximum value with its edited title and informative answer. Let's keep it closed.

Comment: @watashinopiza If you are interested in knowing what was meant about [電話](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/電話), read [Wasei-kango](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasei-kango) article in Wikipedia, which explains it and has some examples (including 電話). (There are also some cases, where a word spelt using some combination of *hanzi* previously existed in Chinese, but Japanese created a new meaning of corresponding Sino-Japanese word, and the new meaning was later borrowed from Japan to China.)

Comment: @Arfrever Importing a word and changing its meaning does not surprise me and is not the basis of my question. I'll leave that for later endeavors. As far as it being Japanese or Chinese, I have limited resources and can't verify with 100% confidence one way or the other. I am not surprised people on a Japanese language site will side with the Japanese as the root of all. I am very cautious to accept this since what I have read from the resources I have with me indicate Japan copied China at least historically first. Yes, it is possible in modern times that shifted, but I don't have the proof.

Answer (score 12):

*h* in romanization of Mandarin language is [[x]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative) (and e.g. in Cantonese it is [[h]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_glottal_fricative)).

[[h]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_glottal_fricative) is recently developed consonant in Japanese language itself:

Old Japanese (8th century) and some earlier part of Middle Japanese (which was period generally about 800 - 1600) had [p] and [ᵐb] (i.e. prenasalized, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Japanese#Consonants)). (Prenasalization of *b*, *d*, *z*, *g* existed until at least 17th century.)

Intervocalic [p] changed to [w] in second half of 10th century (according to Frellesvig (2010)), and later, many remaining [p] changed to [[ɸ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_bilabial_fricative) (which is different from [[f]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_labiodental_fricative) but in romanization of Japanese usually romanized as *f*).

[w] (both from original [w] and from [p]) before /i/, /e/, /o/ was lost in various stages in 10th - 13th centuries.

は, ひ, ふ, へ, ほ were still /ɸa/, /ɸi/, /ɸu/, /ɸe/, /ɸo/ at least in 17th century (or in native words in non-initial positions they represented /wa/, /i/, /u/, /je/, /o/).

Probably somewhen in 17th - 19th century /ɸa/, /ɸe/, /ɸo/ started changing to /ha/, /he/, /ho/, and /ɸi/ started changing to /[ç](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_palatal_fricative)i/. Pronunciation with [ɸ] still remains in some dialects, e.g. [Izumo dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umpaku_dialect#Remnants_of_archaic_sounds) (one of Unpaku dialects).

Bjarke Frellesvig (2010, "A History of the Japanese Language", pages 386-387):

> 14.3 Delabialization of /f/; /f/ > /h/
>
> The final change to affect the reflex of OJ /p/ was the change of /f/ (see 11.3) to /h/ which occurred at some point during NJ. This change was primarily a phonetic change with no mergers or other immediate phonemic impact and it was therefore not reflected in general writing. Thunberg (1792) mostly writes words reflecting LMJ /f/ with 'f' (e.g. *fanna* 'flower'), but says that words with 'f' sometimes are pronounced ('read') with 'h' (e.g. *hanna*) and Siebold (1826) uses 'h' in his transliteration of the kana letters はひふへほ, but notes that they are often pronounced with 'f'. However, by the middle of the nineteenth century, sources in alphabet writing generally write 'h', except before 'u' where it is 'f', reflecting that /h/ is pronounced [ɸ] before /u/. Hepburn's transcription system from the end of the nineteenth century adopted this allophonic notation which since then has dominated transcriptions in the west. Very recently, due to a large intake of loanwords from English, [ɸ] has become phonemic /f/ before vowels other than /u/ (14.6).

<sub>(Bjarke Frellesvig's book uses different phonemic analysis than my analysis. I prefer to use /ɸ/ instead of /f/ in phonemic notation of Japanese.)</sub>

[[x]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative) and [[h]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_glottal_fricative) sound similarly, but when Japanese language had neither of them, the consonant sounding most close to [x] or [h] (e.g. in words in Chinese languages) amongst available consonants in Japanese language was [[k]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_plosive), and therefore [k] was used during borrowing (e.g. from Chinese languages). [x] and [k] have the same place of articulation, but different manner of articulation.

When words are borrowed from one language to another language, and source language contains sounds not existing in target language, only very rarely those sounds are introduced in target language. Known historical example is that ancient Romans in first century BCE [introduced letters Y and Z at the end of Latin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet#Classical_Latin_alphabet) to write words borrowed from Ancient Greek, which had [/y/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_rounded_vowel) and [/d͡z/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_alveolar_affricate#Voiced_alveolar_sibilant_affricate) ~ /zd/, later [/z/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_alveolar_fricative) ([discussion on pronunciation of zeta here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta#Uses)) in Ancient Greek. But less educated Romans were probably pronouncing Y as [i].

Comment: Great answer. Just hope it is appreciated by OP. So the short answer is our ancestors couldn't distinguish /k/, /kʰ/ and /x/? This Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Chinese) lists 見, 溪 and 曉, respectively, as examples for those three initials. I wondered how 曉 ended up with /g/ but it turned out it's きょう in both 呉音 and 漢音 and ぎょう is 慣用音.

Comment: @aguijonazo Maybe some scholars, monks, nobles etc. received proper education in Middle Chinese and could speak it properly, but it is possible that even they, when using Chinese-origin words in Japanese sentences, were using sounds assimilated to Japanese sound system. And persons without education in Middle Chinese may even have been unawere of /kʰ/, /x/ etc. if they only saw written text. If Japanese government wanted to more faithfully preserve Chinese sounds in borrowed words, then government would have to extend hiragana, katakana...

Comment: I have personally “introduced” the /f/ sound into Japanese and now pronounce ふ with it because it is easier that way. I try not to do so when I’m teaching someone Japanese but it sounds awkward in my head.

Comment: I don't see how /kʰ explains anything here. This has to do with how you pronounce a word with a "k" sound. It doesn't have anything to do with the spelling. If Japanese pronounced Shanghai "Shankhai" then maybe we would have something, but they go the other way. They say "Shan" and "hai". They take out the /kʰ sound entirely.

Comment: @watashinopiza You're confusing things by bringing up Shanghai once again.  We've explained already why place names may not follow the more traditional readings.

Comment: @watashinopiza Japanese would have pronounced 上海 with a k sound now if they took the name from the Sui/Tang dynasties. But they didn't, they took the name from Mandarin. Let's use another example: 長安 is rendered as *Chou'an* in Japanese, because they imported the name from antiquity. If they imported the name from Mandarin, it would be *Chan'an*.

Comment: @dROOOze - I know you don't need to be educated on these things but I would have to say that's a bit misleading. Chinese place names don't have to be imported from antiquity to be read in the Japanese ways. 海城 is かいじょう and 凌海 is りょうかい. These may be better examples to make this OP somehow understand 上海 is an exception, if they ever will.

Comment: @aguijonazo You're right, but in any case, "かいじょう" and "りょうかい" are not words imported from Mandarin. You might consider them to be imported from a vague notion of "Chinese", as (1) a calque or (2) what Wiktionary terms as [Orthographic Borrowing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#orthographic_borrowing).

Comment: @dROOOze - Please explain this OP that *shòusī* in Chinese is one of those cases. They don't seem to get it and keep bringing up some theories about where 寿司 as a food originated...

Comment: @dROOze The question had NOTHING to do with place names. I was asking about "deep sea" and the letters "k" and "h". An appropriate answer was given.

Comment: @dROOze The sushi talk was a side issue. Of course people are going to side with Japan on a Japanese language site. I don't expect there to NOT be bias.

Comment: @watashinopiza Your question starts with the matter of the pronunciation of Shanghai in Japanese vs Chinese.  You've brought the subject up of Shanghai over and over again.  You keep making this about the name of a place "Shanghai".  You yourself have made this all about place names.  If it's not about place names, then stop bringing up the matter of Shanghai--it is quite literally a exception to an otherwise fairly consistent rule in Japanese.

Comment: @A.Ellett The main question has to do with "deep sea" (shinkai). This is not a proper noun for a place. I did compare it to Shanghai (or in Japanese "shanhai") merely for comparison sake. Weigh it 20%. Weigh the "deap sea (shinkai) 80%. That is the meat and potatoes of my question, why there is a difference. I am not bringing up Shanghai, I am bringing up the "kai". I have repeatedly asked why not "umi" or "una". Then, after discussion with Arfrever I came across an answer that Japanese never had an "h" at the time. This is good enough explanation and it doesn't revolve around "Shanghai".

Comment: @watashinopiza "kai" is the standard on'yomi reading.  It seems to me that you do not understand some fundamentals of Japanese use of kanji.  There is *on* and *kun* readings.  If you understand the difference between *on* and *kun* then you should be able to understand the difference between *kai* and *umi*.  I don't know where you got *una*, that is not a standard reading.  Nor is *hai* a standard reading.

Comment: @watashinopiza There is absolutely nothing remarkable about 深海.  In each of the following compounds, 海 is read as "kai": [海岸]{かいがん}, [海路]{かいろ}, [海底]{かいてい}, [海上]{かいじょう}, [海中]{かいちゅう} and many many more.

Comment: @watashinopiza Whether Japanese had a "h" sound at the time the kanji was borrowed from China is really irrelevant.  We know that historically speaking, when 海 was borrowed from China, in the region where it was borrowed from, the pronunciation was not an "h" as it is pronounced now.   But, this is the point of the answer above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151367/discussion-between-watashinopiza-and-a-ellett).

Comment: @A.Ellett I disagree with "irrelevant" in your last comment. If Japanese had [h] or [x], then separate set of *hiragana* and *katakana* characters would have been developed for *ha*, *hi*, *hu*, *he*, *ho*. When *hiragana* and *katakana* were initially created, は was used for *pa* and *ba*, ひ was used for *pi* and *bi* etc. And what was pronunciation of 海 in that region, according to you?